# How to commit changes to a Subversion repository using TextMate

Tags: svn, textmate, commit

I'm just trying out TextMate now as a replacement for the extremely powerful, but extremely ugly PHPStorm (on my Mac).

Everything is fine except for SVN. I have my working copy already on disk, and TextMate correctly shows me the SVN metadata for any file I open from that working copy.

But, now that I made a change to a file and I want to commit it to the repository, when I say commit and click OK on the commit dialog, all I get is a dialog window saying "Transmitting file data" and an indeterminate progress bar sitting there forever. (There is no cancel button to stop it, so I have to quit TextMate to get out of it.)

Obviously I'm too stupid. Where do I tell TextMate my svn credentials, so it can write to the repository? Shouldn't it have to ask me for the username and password before I can commit?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed the issue by opening Terminal on my Mac and connecting to my remote Subversion repository with the command below.

$ svn checkout https://yourusername.svn.beanstalkapp.com/

I was then prompted for my Beanstalk password. Once I made the connection via Terminal, the Textmate SVN bundle worked as expected.

Comment: This was the solution for me, and confirmed in #textmate as the way to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

When using subversion bundle Commit (⌃⇧A + 5) you have no feedback.
Try Status (⌃⇧A + 0) instead and then hit Commit button.
You'll probably see, just what I saw:

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.yourserver.com:443':
```

the problem is: there's no way to provide user input via textmate.
if you get this message in terminal you'd hit p for accept (p)ermanently and ther'd be no issue

Here is probably the answer: http://unfuddle.com/community/forums/5/topics/752
but so far I don't quite understand where to put the certificate file
I'll ley you know as soon as I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen in the case where the `svn` binary is updated and no longer has access to Keychain. Trying a `svn diff` or `svn status` from the command line will work, but if you try a test commit you'll get a Keychain popup:

[image: screenshot]

"Always Allow" this access, and Textmate will start working again.